# backbone.js unbind function from model when destroy view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to destroy view and make other view for a model.
but I can not unbind functions binded to model from old view.

my test code

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
       this.model.bind('change',this.render);
    },

    destroy_view: function() {

       //COMPLETELY UNBIND THE VIEW
       this.undelegateEvents();

       this.$el.removeData().unbind();

       //Remove view from DOM
       this.remove();
       Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
   },
});
```

and I made new model and view, and I destroy view like this

```
view.destroy_veiw();
delete view;
```

but stil render is called when model changed

```
model.triger('change');
```

I know model.unbind(); can solve this problem , but it will unbind other functions , I want use this model for other view. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);            
    }
});
```

Comment: I suggest `this.model.on('change',this.render,this);` (third argument) instead of `_.bindAll(this);`, which can [cause problems](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/2080) in some cases when the class you extended expects a different context in some method. Also suggest using `this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render)` instead, since the default View `remove` method already calls `stopListening`.